# Can you give me a detailed description of (spetral) deferred correction method?

Tags: parallel-computing, ode, numerical-analysis

I have just read "Accelerating the convergence of spectral deferred correction methods". The link is here: http://www.unc.edu/~junjia/papers/sdcgmres.pdf‎.

But I wonder how to understand deferred correction method. Can you give me a description of this method? Or any other papers or books to read to understand this method?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I may want to add a parallel-computing tag because I think PFASST has something to do with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original paper on SDC is "Spectral deferred correction methods for ordinary differential equations" by Dutt, Greengard, and Rokhlin.  There are few papers by M Minion (see [his old research page](http://amath.unc.edu/Minion/Publications)) that explain SDC as well.  Note that these methods belong to a larger class of defect/deferred correction strategies -- lots of literature out there, please see references in the above.  Finally, SDC methods stand on their own apart from PFASST, although they are a fundamental piece of the PFASST algorithm.